# Why use IList over IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net

1) I read some (general) code snippet and saw some places that used `IList<T>` and some used `IEnumerable`. What is the pros to use the first over the latter?

2) `is` and `as` in c#.
I understand  `is` does type check and `as` does casting.
But what is exactly casting? forcing data to some sized object? when `is` and `as` differ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A `IList[<T>]` represents something that:

- can be iterated
- is of finite, known size
- is repeatable
- can be accessed randomly by index
- can (optionally, checkable) be edited: reassign values, add, remove, etc

An `IEnumerable`, on the other hand, can only be iterated. Not all things that can be iterated are lists. For example:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Get() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    while(true) yield return rand.Next();
}
```

that ^^^ is an infinite sequence. It has no length, cannot be mutated, cannot be accessed by index... however, it can be iterated:

```
foreach(int i in Get().Take(200)) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

---

`is` performs a type check that returns `true`/`false`... i.e. ***is*** `obj` an `IList`? yes or no.

`as` performs a "try to do this" type-check; it returns `null` if it *fails*, or a typed reference (etc) if it is successful. Basically, it is an efficiency thing:

```
if(obj is IList) {
    var list = (IList) obj;
    ...
}
```

is less efficient than:

```
var list = obj as IList;
if(list != null) {
    ...
}
```

<s>they also behave differently if `obj` is null; `is` throws an exception; `as` returns `null`.</s>

Comment: Have you actually measured the performance of those two? The IL instruction isinst though it names suggests that it's correspond to is actually corresponds to the as operation. There's no is operation in IL. In reality is in IL is `obj as type != null` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is.aspx. So the choice should be on readability I'd say

Comment: @RuneFS I regularly code in IL, so I'm very aware of that. The difference, however, is the extra castclass **after** the isinst. It is, I admit, a tiny difference.

Comment: I think the JIT compiler should be able to optimize out that classcast. But I don't know if it currently does.

Comment: ANYWAY! the fundamental point: they do different things... `is` means... "is it?", and `as` means "one of these, if it *is* one of these, otherwise null"

Comment: btw is does not throw an exception if object is null. The expression will evaluate to false:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640043/why-does-the-is-operator-return-false-when-given-null

Comment: @Rune I must be misremembering... my apologies

Comment: But what is exactly casting? forcing data to some sized object?

Comment: @Elad "casting" is an overloaded term, that could be any of: asking the runtime to perform a reference type-check operation, to assert that (for example) an `object` **really is** a `Customer`; converting between primitive types, for example `ushort` to `long`; calling an implicit or explicit static conversion operator, performing a box or unbox, or converting between a wrapped/unwrapped nullable value. In this case, we mean the first: a reference type-check, that doesn't **change** anything - it just checks "is this `object` also an `IList`"

Answer (score 3):

1. `IList` offers certain methods that `IEnumerable` doesn't. Most importantly, the ability to add to it (for more information, check out the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx))
2. `is` compares types, returning if a certain object can be casted to a type. `as` actually performs that cast, returning `null` if it failed. Casting means converting an object of type `A` to an object of type `B`, for whatever reason.

Comment: Most of the time, in C#, casting doesn't convert objects between types. Usually, it just checks whether an object is of a given compile-time type at runtime, and if so allows you to assign the object into a variable of said type. (If not, returns `null` or throws an exception, depending on if you use parens or `as`.)

Comment: Indeed, it more commonly refers to coercion, not conversion