# Do "x as X != null" and "x is X" always return the same result?

Tags: c#, .net, operators, type-conversion, comparison-operators

Is there any situation where these two if statements will produce different results?

```
if(x as X != null)
{
  // Do something
}

if(x is X)
{
  // Do something
}
```

**Edit: To clarify:** I know what is the difference between the operators (in general) and what they mean. The question is if there is any situation where these two would produce different results.

Comment: `x as X` doesn't work if `X` is a non-nullable struct.

Comment: question aside, use x is X, first one is just stupid and create extra casting

Comment: @TimSchmelter `is` returns false if the left side is `null`. They're the same in that regard.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer on another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/496167/1324810). It's pretty extensive.

Comment: @kirie: I beg to differ - the first one is just what is done in the `var typedX = x as X; if (typedX != null) { ...` pattern, and that is at least considered to be more performant by FxCop than a check with `is` and a subsequent extra cast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting vs using the 'as' keyword in the CLR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/casting-vs-using-the-as-keyword-in-the-clr)

Comment: @CodesInChaos: i've already recognized it. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640043/why-does-the-is-operator-return-false-when-given-null) the related question. Thanks for pointing that out. Sorry for deleting my comment, i noticed later your comment.

Comment: @O.R. Mapper
Isn't it better to use if(x != null && x is X), this one more readable to me

Comment: both map to the same underlying IL instruction `isinst`

Comment: @kirie: If you use `is` first and then, in the `if` block, perform a typecast, FxCop will complain about a duplicate cast that should be improved into a single `as` with a subsequent `null` comparison for performance reasons. It wouldn't create any noticeable difference in most scenarios, though. In any case, the `null` check in your statement is obsolete nonetheless, as it is basically included in the `is` check. cf. [CA1800](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any situation where these two if statements will produce different results?

First, note that there are more restrictions on the use of `as` than of `is`, so `x is X` may compile in cases where `(x as X) != null` may not. For example, `as` requires that the specified type be a reference type or a nullable type; `is` works with non-nullable value types as well.

Assume now that both `x is X` and `(x as X) != null` are valid expressions. According to §7.10.11 of the C# 4.0 specification, "the operation `E as T` produces the same result as `E is T ? (T)(E) : (T)null`". If we plug that latter expression into `(x as X) != null`, we get

```
    (x as X) != null
==  ((x is X) ? (X)x : null) != null  // by the definition of "as"
==  (x is X) ? ((X)x != null) : (null != null)  // distribute
==  (x is X) ? true : false  // because (x is X) implies (x != null)
==  x is X
```

This proves that `x is X` and `(x as X) != null` are equivalent if both are valid expressions.

Comment: Thanks for quoting the C# specification. Seems plausible!

Answer (score 6):

There functionally is no difference between the 2 statements.  In general the `as` version is used to avoid a double type test because you can do the following

```
var local = x as X;
if (local != null) { 
  // Sweet I have local! 
}
```

vs.

```
if (x is X) { 
  // This runs the type check yet again 
  var local = (X)x; 
}
```

If you aren't actually using the value after the type test then just use the `is` version

Answer (score 2):

If `x` is a non-nullable type (or a generic type not constrained to be a nullable type) then the first option won't compile; the second is the only option.

Beyond that, they're the same.

Comment: `null is ...` returns false. Even in the degenerate case `object o = null; Assert.IsFalse(o is object)`

Answer (score 0):

In this case:

```
if(x as X != null)
{
  // Do something
}
```

You are first attempting to cast `x` to type `X` before comparing to null (i.e. whether the cast succeeded or not).

In this other case:

```
if(x is X)
{
  // Do something
}
```

You are simply asking whether `x` is of type `X` and no casting is done.

Comment: Which is equivalent in the cases where it compiles

Comment: Does not answer the question whether the if statements are functionally the same...

Comment: @aKzenT One does the casting and the other does not, how does not answer the question?

Comment: Question is: Is there any situation where these two if statements will produce different results?

Comment: @aKzenT but the question title asks something else. Even the first line of your question: *Is there a difference between the following if statements?* Please edit that to make it clear if you're that specific.