# Update List<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List `List<CartLine> linecollection` where `CartLine` is a custom datatype defined by the class

```
class CartLine
{ 
    public Product {get;set;}
    public Quantity {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to search in my List using LINQ as `CartLine line = linecollection.Where(P=>P.Product.ProductId==product.ProductID).FirstOrDefault()` where lowercase `product` is parameter passed to method. Now if `line` is `null` I can add item to `linecollection` easily. If it´s not `null` then I just want to add `quantity` (another parameter passed to the method) to the `Quantity` of searched item in the list.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to update the `Quantity` of the object you just pulled out of the list with `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: Your code won't even compile.  What are the types of `Product` and `Quantity`?

Comment: It´s quite hard to guess what you´re asking. If the query does not return any item (`line = null`) you want to add anything to your list, right? And if it not `null` you want to add `quantity`? But as your list is a list of type `CartLine` you can´t add a `quantity`, but only `Cartline`-instances. So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I want to update the Quantity of that object but it should also be updated in my List linecollection!

Comment: I understand what you're asking, but your code, as it stands, wont' compile.  Get your code to compile, then update your question to include code that actually compiles.

Comment: If line!=null then it means there is already an object with same id in the list i want to add quantity to the Quantity property of that object already in the list!

Comment: Stop adding comments with exclamation points at the end!  It makes us feel like you're angry at us for trying to help you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Program
    {
        static List<CartLine> linecollection = new List<CartLine>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProductClass product = new ProductClass() { ProductID = 0 };

            linecollection.Add(new CartLine() { Product = product, Quantity = 80 });
            linecollection.Add(new CartLine() { Product = new ProductClass() { ProductID = 1 }, Quantity = 60 });
            linecollection.Add(new CartLine() { Product = new ProductClass() { ProductID = 2 }, Quantity = 40 });

            CartLine line = linecollection.Where(P => P.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (line == null)
                linecollection.Add(new CartLine() { Quantity = 100 });
            else
                line.Quantity = 100;
        }
    }

    class CartLine
    {
        public ProductClass Product
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public int Quantity
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }

    class ProductClass
    {
        public int ProductID
        {
            get; set;
        }
    }
```

You can also shorten your LINQ query to:

```
CartLine line = linecollection.Where(P => P.Product == product).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: As you mentioned line.Quantity=100; in this way how the object in the List is updated I mean Line is another copy of that object not that object exactly?

Comment: Try it, you will see that the item of List will be updated ;-)

Comment: Where did you get `ProductClass` and `int` for the types of `Product` and `Quantity` properties?  You're making assumptions I think.  Until the OP provides code that compiles, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Right, I only assume that structure. But I accuse the OP that he will be able to adapt the sample to his solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As `CartLine` is a class, the LINQ statement returns a reference to the actual list member. The `quantity` can be added as follows.

```
if (line is CartLine)
{
    line.Quantity += quantity;
}
```

Comment: With calling FirstOrDefault() line is always of Type CartLine.

Comment: To my understanding, `FirstOrDefault` will return `null` for a reference type, and according to [this explanation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/scekt9xw.aspx) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640043/why-does-the-is-operator-return-false-when-given-null), the `is` operator will return `false` on `null`.

Comment: Yes, it will return null. But this is only the value. CartLine is the type. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx for FirstOrDefault().

Comment: FirstOrDefault will always return the generic type T of List<T>, whether it's value is null or not.

Comment: @c0d3b34n You're right, but the `is` operator returns `false` on `null`; if `line` is set to `null`, the expressions `line is CartLine` will evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

When you query *does* return an item and you update this item, the reference within the list also gets updated. So when using

```
CartLine line = linecollection.Where(P => P.Product.ProductId == product.ProductID).FirstOrDefault();
line.Quantity = ...
```

also the item in your list gets updated as it simply references the same item you retrieved using your query. This is basics of *reference-types*. Your list does only dontain **references** to your actual objects, so whenever you update any instance of those objects those changes are reflected in all references - for example in your list.

You can check this by re-querying your item from the list and getting its quantity:

```
var updatedQuantity = linecollection.Where(P => P.Product.ProductId == product.ProductID).First().Quantity;
```

Which should now be equal the `quantitty` you´ve set.