# Why does pattern matching on a nullable result in syntax errors?

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, nullable, c#-7.0

I like to use `pattern-matching` on a `nullable int` i.e. `int?`:

```
int t  = 42;
object tobj = t;    
if (tobj is int? i)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"It is a nullable int of value {i}");
}
```

However, this results in the following syntax errors:

- [CS1003: Syntax error, ';'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1003),
- [CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1525),
- [CS0103: The name 'i' does not exist in the current context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103).

'i)' is marked with a red squiggly line.

The expression compiles when using the old operator `is`:

```
int t = 42;
object tobj = t;    
if (tobj is int?)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($"It is a nullable int");
}


string t = "fourty two";
object tobj = t;
if (tobj is string s)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine($@"It is a string of value ""{s}"".");
}
```

Also works as expected.

*(I'm using [c#-7.2](/questions/tagged/c%23-7.2) and tested with both [.net-4.7.1](/questions/tagged/.net-4.7.1) and [.net-4.6.1](/questions/tagged/.net-4.6.1))*

I thought it had something to with operator precedence.  Therefore, I have tried using parenthesis at several places but this didn't help.

Why does it give these syntax errors and how can I avoid them?

Comment: Why are you trying to use nullable types? Are you trying to create optional values with pattern matching, something like F#'s discriminated unions? They are coming, just not in the C# 8 timeframe (I think). You can emulate them if you create two separate types for the valid and missing values with a common interface, eg `interface IOption<T>{}; class MyValidClass:IOption<T>{...} class MyEmptyType:IOption<T>{}`. The interface and options don't even need to have any methods

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the nullable types came from a different part of the code, the choice to use nullable types is not related to the pattern matching I attempted here.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The type pattern in its various forms: `x is T y`, `case T y` etc, [always fails to match when `x` is `null`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1203#issuecomment-353474285). This is because [`null` doesn't have a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640043/why-does-the-is-operator-return-false-when-given-null/7640437#7640437), so asking "is this `null` of this type?" is a meaningless question.

Therefore `t is int? i` or `t is Nullable<int> i` makes no sense as a pattern: either `t` is an `int`, in which case `t is int i` will match anyway, or it's `null`, in which case no type pattern can result in a match.

And that is the reason why `t is int? i` or `t is Nullable<int> i` are not, and probably never will be, supported by the compiler.

The reason why you get additional errors from the compiler when using `t is int? i` is due to the fact that, e.g. `t is int? "it's an int" : "no int here"` is valid syntax, thus the compiler gets confused over your attempts to use `?` for a nullable type in this context.

As to how can you avoid them, the obvious (though probably not very helpful) answer is: don't use nullable types as the type in type patterns. A more useful answer would require you to explain *why* you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 6):

Change your code into:

```
int t = 42;
object tobj = t;
if (tobj is Nullable<int> i)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"It is a nullable int of value {i}");
}
```

This produces the more helpful:

- CS8116: It is not legal to use nullable type 'int?' in a pattern; use the underlying type 'int' instead <sup>*(Could not find documentation about CS8116 to reference)*</sup>

Others (user [@Blue0500 at github](https://github.com/Blue0500) ) have tagged this behaviour as a bug [Roslyn issue #20156](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20156). Reacting to [Roslyn issue #20156](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20156), [Julien Couvreur](https://github.com/jcouv) from Microsoft has said he thinks it is by design.
[Neal Gafter](https://github.com/gafter) from Microsoft working on Roslyn has also said [better diagnostics are wanted for use of nullable type is switch pattern](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16708).

So, the error message can be avoided by using:

```
int t = 42;
object tobj = t;
if (tobj == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"It is null");
}
else if (tobj is int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"It is a int of value {i}");
}
```

Except for [issues when parsing](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/10492) `tobj is int? i`, this still leaves the question why is `tobj is int? i` or `tobj is Nullable<int> i` not allowed.

Comment: Would not fit better to what the user wnats to do to use `if(t.GetType() == typeof(int?))`?

Comment: I guess in all samples in your question and answer, `t is` should be `tobj is`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone wondering how to actually use pattern matching with nullables, you can do so with a generic helper function, like so:

```
public static bool TryConvert<T>(object input, out T output)
{
    if (input is T result)
    {
        output = result;
        return true;
    }
    output = default(T);
    // Check if input is null and T is a nullable type.
    return input == null && System.Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null;
}
```

This will return `true` if `T` is a nullable or non-nullable of the same type that `input` contains or if `input` is null and `T` is nullable. Basically works the same as normal, but also handles nullables.

---

Side note: Interestingly, from my testing, I found `System.Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T))` allocates 40 bytes of garbage every time it's called if T is nullable. Not sure why, seems like a bug to me, but that's potentially a hefty price to pay rather than just null-checking like normal.

Knowing that, here's a better function:

```
public static bool TryConvert<T>(object input, out T? output) where T : struct
{
    if (input is T result)
    {
        output = result;
        return true;
    }
    output = default(T?);
    return input == null;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Now you can use the following syntax that works for classic object as weel as Nullable :

```
public static void Check(int? value)
{
    if (value is {} v)
    {
        // Happy path
    }
}
```